# Correlation coefficient of a WSS process

Tags: probability

Could someone please tell me why the correlation coefficient of a WSS process is :

$$\rho_{XX}(\tau) = \frac{\operatorname{K}_{XX}(\tau)}{\sigma^2} = \frac{\operatorname{E}[(X_t - \mu)(X_{t+\tau} - \mu)]}{\sigma^2}$$

Instead of :

$$\rho_{XX}(\tau) = \frac{\operatorname{K}_{XX}(\tau)}{\sigma_{t}\sigma_{t+\tau}} = \frac{\operatorname{E}[(X_t - \mu)(X_{t+\tau} - \mu)]}{\sigma_{t}\sigma_{t+\tau}} $$

?

Where :$~~~\sigma_{t}^2=\sigma^2=\operatorname{E}[X^2(t)]-\operatorname{E}^2[X(t)]$  .

Stated in another way , does a WSS process imply  that :

$$\operatorname{E}[X^2(t+\tau)]=\operatorname{E}[X^2(t)]$$ ?

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak stationary implies that for all fixed $\tau$, the function $t\mapsto \mathbb E\left[X_{t+\tau}X_t\right]$ is constant. In particular, choosing $\tau=0$ shows that $\mathbb E\left[X_{t+0}X_t\right]=\mathbb E\left[X_t^2\right]=\mathbb E\left[X_0^2\right]$. The other part of the definition of weakly stationary process implies that the expectation of $X_t$ does not depend on $t$ hence we can safely define $\sigma^2:=\operatorname{Var}\left(X_t\right)$.

Comment: I do understand that part but the problem is why they've replaced $\sigma_{t}\sigma_{t+\tau}$ by $\sigma^2_{t}$ ?

Comment: Because $\sigma_{t+\tau}=\sigma_{t}$.

Comment: This is the very relation that I am trying to prove/understand , how is this equality justified : $$\sigma(t+\tau) =(\operatorname{E}[X^2(t+\tau)]-\operatorname{E}^2[X(t+\tau)])^\frac{1}{2}~=~(\operatorname{E}[X^2(t+\tau)]-\operatorname{E}^2[X(t)])^\frac{1}{2}~ =? 
~(\operatorname{E}[X^2(t)]-\operatorname{E}^2[X(t)])^\frac{1}{2} $$


So basically why : 
 $$\operatorname{E}[X^2(t)]~ =~\operatorname{E}[X^2(t+\tau)]$$  
?